# How to assign a group of array elements a value in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

I want to initialize a group of array elements the same value using a single line. I know I could use a for loop, but I want to know if there is a way simpler way to do it.

for e.g., I have an array of zeros. And I want to initialize elements 4 to 9 as 1. I would think of doing something like,

```
my @array = (0) x 10;
for my $i (3 .. 8) {
    $array[$i] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use an array slice?

```
@array = (0) x 10;
@array[3..8] = (1) x 6;   # or something > 6
```

This is easier to understand than a `splice` and clearer than a `map`.

Instead of supplying a single index, we use a list `[3..8]`. We have to adjust the sigil to `@`, because we want a list context.

Answer (score 5):

One approach:

```
my @array = (0) x 3, (1) x 6, 0;
```

Another approach:

```
my @array = map { $_ >= 3 && $_ <= 8 ? 1 : 0 } (0 .. 9);
```

Or, if you mean that you've already set `@array` to `(0) x 10`, and are just looking for a one-liner to set a range of values to `1`:

```
splice @array, 3, 6, (1) x 6;
```